# compare a positive or negative value and add an arrow

Tags: angular

I'm stuck in my condition.
When the number is greater than 0% a green arrow should be displayed.
But when the number is less than 0% a red arrow should be displayed.

My problem is that when I have -0.13% both arrows show up. I do not understand why?? Normally the arrow should be red.

```
<div class="" style="width: 20% !important;">
    <h5 style="text-align: right;">
        {{ n.variation | number:'1.2-2' | projectformatnum }}&nbsp;%
        <span *ngIf="n.last >= 0"
            style="
                background: url(/assets/images/project-online-sprites.png) -296px -834px no-repeat; 
                position: relative; 
                top: 3px;
                margin-left: 10px;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="n.variation < 0"
        style="
            background: url(/assets/images/project-online-sprites.png) 1px -834px no-repeat; 
            position: relative; 
            top: 3px;
            margin-left: 10px;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </span>
    </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: what is n.last in that case?

Comment: @Aakash Garg: You're right, i haven't seen the variable, it's ok now. thank you so much. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems in the first one you use

```
n.last >= 0
```

but in the second one you use

```
n.variation < 0
```

if you want to be more precise you can use ***else*** like:

```
    <div class="" style="width: 20% !important;">
        <h5 style="text-align: right;">
            {{ n.variation | number:'1.2-2' | projectformatnum }}&nbsp;%
            <span *ngIf="n.last >= 0; else otherstuff"
                style="
                    background: url(/assets/images/project-online-sprites.png) -296px -834px no-repeat; 
                    position: relative; 
                    top: 3px;
                    margin-left: 10px;">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </span>
<ng-template  #otherstuff>
            <span
            style="
                background: url(/assets/images/project-online-sprites.png) 1px -834px no-repeat; 
                position: relative; 
                top: 3px;
                margin-left: 10px;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>
</ng-template>
        </h5>
    </div>
```